# How to SUM using group_concat with group by on differents tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have 3 tables: Users, Tools,tool_assigned:

User:

| id | name | department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | a |
| 2 | peter | b |
| 3 | paul | a |

Tools:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tool1 |
| 2 | tool2 |
| 3 | tool3 |

Tool_assigned:

| id | id_user | id_tool | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 9 | 3 | 3 | 1 |

I need to get this result:

| id_tool | tool_name | total_quantity | summary_department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tool1 | 5 | a-1, b-2, c-2 |
| 2 | tool2 | 7 | a-3, b-3, c-1 |
| 3 | tool3 | 3 | a-1, b-1, c-1 |

I've tried doing a query that can get that result, but the best I've gotten so far is this:

```
SELECT tool.id, tool.name, sum(tool_assigned.quantity) as total_quantity, 
       group_concat(user.deparment, '-', tool_asigned.quantity) as summary_department 
FROM tool_assigned 
INNER JOIN users ON tool_assigned.id_user = user.id 
INNER JOIN tools ON tool_assigned.id_tool = tool.id 
GROUP BY tools.name, users.department
```

Please help me, I've already tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two levels of aggregation: first by tool and department, then by tool only. You could phrase this as:

```
select t.id, t.name as tool_name, 
    sum(x.quantity) as total_quantity,  
    group_concat(x.info order by x.department) as summary_department
from tools t
inner join (
    select ta.id_tool, u.department, concat(u.name, '-', sum(t.quantity)) as info 
    from tool_assigned ta 
    inner join users on ta.id_user = u.id 
    group by ta.id_tool, u.department
) x on x.id_tool = t.id
group by t.id
```

Comment: Your answer helped me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a `with` statment

```
with tools_per_dept as (
    SELECT users.department as dept,
           tool.id as tool_id,
           tool.name as tool_name,
           sum(tool_assigned.quantity) as total_quantity
    FROM tool_assigned
             INNER JOIN users ON tool_assigned.id_user = user.id
             INNER JOIN tools ON tool_assigned.id_tool = tool.id
    GROUP BY tools.name, users.department
)
select tool_id,
       tool_name,
       sum(total_quantity) as total,
       group_concat(dept, '-', total_quantity) as summary_department 
from tools_per_dept
group by tool_id, tool_name
```